Android Auto - CarAppService not showing on car
I am developing an app where I am supposed to render a grid of icons, now the problem is that in the DHU it displays correctly and works, while in the auto it does not display.
This is my manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="androidx.car.app.NAVIGATION_TEMPLATES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"
        android:required="true"/>



    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:appCategory="audio">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
            android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.car.app.minCarApiLevel"
            android:value="5" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppMetadataHolderService.CAR_APP_SERVICE"
            android:value=".CarMainService" />

        <service
            android:name=".CarMainService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/auto"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
                <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.NAVIGATION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>

Instead, these are the dependencies:
enter image description here
I expect CarAppService to be displayed in the android auto menu

Apps built using the Car App Library are only available for use on real head units when distributed via the Play Store or another trusted source: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#real-vehicles
